# MS SQL json query/where clause nested array items

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I have json data that i can query on using `CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(` which gets slow once you start adding multiple cross applies or once your json document get too large. So i wanted to add an index on the data im trying to filter on, but i cant get the syntax on nested array items to work with out using a cross apply. As such i cant create an index as you cant use a cross apply when making an index. According to the MS docs i should just be able to do

```sql
JSON_query(my_column, $.parentItem.nestedItemsArray1.nestedItemsArray2)
```

I should be able to get all the values of the nested, array items to then query on and improve performance by adding an index, something like this

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable 
ADD vdata AS JSON_query(my_column, 
  $.parentItem.nestedItemsArray1.nestedItemsArray2')  
  
CREATE INDEX idx_json_my_column ON mytable(vdata)
```

but the above  `$.array.arrayitems` syntax doesn't work ?
On a side note, I cant help but think in relational terms where normally in Sql you would index a column of data like so

```
col
---
 1| 
 2|
 3|
```

But json data seem to get flattened so when i use JSON_QUERY as per MS example i get "1,2,3" " I assume i want to incdex an array of values rather than a flattened version unless the index will return the inner data of the fattened data ?

my plug and play working example

```sql
declare  @mydata table (    
  ID int NOT NULL,  
  jsondata varchar(max) NOT NULL  
)

INSERT INTO @mydata (id, jsondata)
    VALUES (789, '{ "Id": "12345", "FinanceProductResults": [ { "Term": 12, "AnnualMileage": 5000, "Deposits": 0, "ProductResults": [] }, { "Term": 18, "AnnualMileage": 30000, "Deposits": 15000, "ProductResults": [] }, { "Term": 24, "AnnualMileage": 5000, "Deposits": 0, "ProductResults": [ { "Key": "HP", "Payment": 460.28 } ] }, { "Term": 24, "AnnualMileage": 10000, "Deposits": 0, "ProductResults": [ { "Key": "HP", "Payment": 500.32 } ] }]}')

SELECT 
    j_Id
    ,JSON_query (c.value, '$.Term') as Term
    ,JSON_Value (c.value, '$.AnnualMileage') as AnnualMileage
    ,JSON_Value (c.value, '$.Deposits') as Deposits     
    ,JSON_Value (p.value, '$.Key') as [Key]
    ,JSON_Value (p.value, '$.Payment') as Payment
    --,c.value
FROM @mydata  f 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(f.jsondata)
        WITH (j_Id nvarchar(100) '$.Id')
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(f.jsondata, '$.FinanceProductResults') AS c
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(c.value, '$."ProductResults"') AS p
where 
    ID = 789 
    AND JSON_Value (p.value, '$.Payment') = '460.28'
```

I'm using these MS docs to guide me :

[How to create an index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612798.aspx)

[How to get data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921890.aspx)

**Update**

I was able to improve performance slightly using the "with" method

```sql
SELECT 
    j_Id,
    FinanceDetails.Term,
    FinanceDetails.AnnualMileage,
    FinanceDetails.Deposits,
    Payments.Payment
FROM @mydata  f 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(f.jsondata)
        WITH (j_Id nvarchar(100) '$.Id')
    OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (f.jsondata, '$.FinanceProductResults' )  
            WITH (   
                Term            INT             '$.Term',  
                AnnualMileage   INT             '$.AnnualMileage',  
                Deposits        INT             '$.Deposits',  
                ProductResults  NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.ProductResults'  AS JSON  
            ) AS FinanceDetails
        OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(ProductResults,  '$') 
            WITH (   
                Payment DECIMAL(19, 4)          '$.Payment' 
            ) AS Payments
WHERE   
    Payments.Payment = 460.28
```

but i still like to add an index on the sub array data to aid in improving performance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you cannot index nested properties.
Is Full-text search possible option? You might create FTS on JSON column and add predicate:

```
WHERE ....
AND CONTAINS( jsondata, 'NEAR(('Payments,460),1)')
```

Since JSON is text, this predicate will filter out all records that don't have something like "Payment" and 460 near to each other (this will identify key:value pairs), and you can apply CROSS APPLY on the reduced set of rows.

Comment: Its a shame as i was hoping that because MS SQL 2016, sort of supported json; that it would support indexing on nested items. Still at least I know now I know I wasn't missing something and that its just not possible , thanks :)